# Change Webcam settings in Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, video, webcam, directshow

I am using [this component](http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample) in my Delphi app for working with Webcamera. Now I need to change Webcam parameters (gain, Brightness, ...). I tried to use this

```
var VideoImage   : TVideoImage;
...
VideoImage.SetVideoPropertySettings(VP_Gain, 2, false);
```

This code is functional for Webcam brands such as HP and Microsoft but not PS3 EYE Camera. The code does not cause the error only nothing changes.

I found that the problem is in SetVideoPropertySettings implementation. For PS3 Eye Camera variable pIAMVideoProcAmp is null.

```
FUNCTION TVideoSample.SetVideoPropAmpEx(Prop: TVideoProcAmpProperty; pCapsFlags  : TVideoProcAmpFlags; pActual: longint): HResult;
BEGIN
  Result := S_False;   
  if pIAMVideoProcAmp = nil then
    exit;
  Result := pIAMVideoProcAmp.Set_(Prop, pActual, pCapsFlags)
END;
```

Is there any option to create variable pIAMVideoProcAmp or change Webcam setings by other way?

Comment: Hello, We need lots lots more information if we are going to try to answer this question.

Comment: Hello. I added some details. Thank you for answer.

Comment: `IAMVideoProcAmp` interface is optional, some video devices have it, others don't. If your video source does not expose the interface, this means there is no programmatic way to change settings (at least using regular way, as opposed to model specific alternate options).

Comment: Thank Roman R. for explanation. How is it possible that the settings for this device can be changed manually via the setting screen caused by code `VideoImage.ShowProperty;`?

Comment: Well, I am not certain whether `IAMVideoProcAmp` is not available for this device, or somehow this component fails to obtain it (does not reach respective code path, esp. failing to get something else higher in code etc.). Your seeing the properties as accessible tells for scenario that it might be a component problem.

Comment: An easy way of checking general availability I can suggest is [`DirectShowCaptureCapabilities `](http://alax.info/blog/1531) app. In generated output you should see "### IAMVideoProcAmp" section with itemized list of available settings. You should be able to access the same via your code.

Comment: I downloaded `DirectShowCaptureCapabilities`. Interfaces `IAMVideoProcAmp` is not in list of my camera. Only interfaces `ISpecifyPropertyPages, IAMFilterMiscFlags` is contained.